# How to override the dispatchOnCommand on the AbstractTokenContract and create a new commmand?

Tags: corda

The UpdateTokenCommand is the one that I want to add in the AbstractTokenContract

```
override fun dispatchOnCommand(commands: List<CommandWithParties<TokenCommand>>, inputs: List<IndexedState<WalletState>>, outputs: List<IndexedState<WalletState>>, attachments: List<Attachment>) {
        super.dispatchOnCommand(commands, inputs, outputs, attachments)
        when (commands.first().value) {
            // Issuances should only contain one issue command.
            is IssueTokenCommand -> verifyIssue(commands.single(), inputs, outputs, attachments)
            // Moves may contain more than one move command.
            is MoveTokenCommand -> verifyMove(commands, inputs, outputs, attachments)
            // Redeems must only contain one redeem command.
            is RedeemTokenCommand -> verifyRedeem(commands.single(), inputs, outputs, attachments)
            // Transfer Command
            is UpdateTokenCommand -> verifyUpdate(commands.single(), inputs, outputs, attachments)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this example in kotlin (https://github.com/corda/samples-kotlin/blob/master/Advanced/obligation-cordapp/contracts-kotlin/src/main/kotlin/net/corda/training/contracts/IOUContract.kt)

The thing to notice is how the IOUState in this contract example actually looks at the command type to determine HOW the contract will verify the transaction on that asset.

```
override fun verify(tx: LedgerTransaction) {
    val command = tx.commands.requireSingleCommand<IOUContract.Commands>()
    when (command.value) {
        is Commands.Issue -> requireThat {
```