# how to create new command for FungibleToken

Tags: corda

how to create new command for FungibleToken?
this is FungibleTokenContract doc.

```
 * The [FungibleToken] contract sub-classes the [AbstractToken] contract which contains the "verify" method.
 * To add functionality to this contract, developers should:
 * 1. Create their own commands which implement the [TokenCommand] interface.
 * 2. Override the [AbstractTokenContract.dispatchOnCommand] method to add support for the new command, remembering
 *    to call the super method to handle the existing commands.
 * 3. Add a method to handle the new command in the new sub-class contract.
```

but how to **Override the [AbstractTokenContract.dispatchOnCommand] method?**

Comment: Didn't you answer your own question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57353436/how-to-override-the-dispatchoncommand-on-the-abstracttokencontract-and-create-a)?

Comment: Sorry about that.   it is not correct. i deleted it .

Answer (score 0):

You can override all the methods of the AbstractTokenContract, as in any Abstract class, so like this:

```
class ExampleTokenContract: AbstractTokenContract<FungibleToken>() {

    override val accepts: Class<FungibleToken> get() = uncheckedCast(FungibleToken::class.java)

    override fun dispatchOnCommand(
            commands: List<CommandWithParties<TokenCommand>>,
            inputs: List<IndexedState<AT>>,
            outputs: List<IndexedState<AT>>,
            attachments: List<Attachment>,
            references: List<StateAndRef<ContractState>>
) {
        // do some logic
  }}
```

Comment: Is it what you were looking for?